# Simple Python Calculator Challenge 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was bored one afternoon and decided to make a simple python calculator that asked for two numbers and performed and operation. It started as a 64 line piece of code and I have simplified it to now be a mere 9 lines of code!!!. I was just curious if anyone could make the code less than 9 lines. Is it possible to have fewer lines and still perform the same action? Please do post what you can come up with, I don't think it can get shorter than 9 lines. Here is what I have written and is completely functional. Python 2.7:

```
num1 = float(raw_input("What will be your first number?:\n"))
num2 = float(raw_input("What will be your second number?:\n"))
Q_3 = raw_input("What will be your operation?:\n")
if Q_3 == "+": print(num1 + num2)
if Q_3 == "-": print(num1 - num2)
if Q_3 == "/": print(num1 / num2)
if Q_3 == "*": print(num1 * num2)
if Q_3 == "%": print(num1 % num2)
if Q_3 == "**": print(num1 ** num2)
```

Comment: Minimizing the number of lines of codes doesn't make a good program, you should try to optimize your program in other ways.

Comment: And what exactly is to be gained by reducing code lines ? And its not completely functional unless it handles input errors.

Comment: This is just out of curiosity. I was curious what was the minimum number of lines of code required to make a functional calculator.(Assuming person input is only integers)

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a better place for this question.

Comment: [The Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator) Single line

Comment: You might want to ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 lines:

```
num1 = float(raw_input("What will be your first number?:\n"))
num2 = float(raw_input("What will be your second number?:\n"))
Q_3 = raw_input("What will be your operation?:\n")
if Q_3 in ("+", "-", "/", "*", "%", "**"):
    print(eval("%s %s %s" % (num1, Q_3, num2)))
```

Or with 4 lines:

```
num1, num2, Q_3 = map(raw_input, ["What will be your first number? ",
    "What will be your second number? ", "What will be your operation? "])
if Q_3 in ("+", "-", "/", "*", "%", "**"):
    print(eval("%s %s %s" % (float(num1), Q_3, float(num2))))
```

Comment: Thanks man that's great thinking!!! And you can even make it 4 lines!!!

Comment: good thinking well done.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JuniorCompressor the new calculator code can be simplified to 2 lines!!

```
num1, num2, Q_3 = map(raw_input, ["What will be your first number? ", "What will be your second number? ", "What will be your operation? "])
if Q_3 in ("+", "-", "/", "*", "%", "**"): print(eval("%s %s %s" % (float(num1), Q_3, float(num2))))
```

Comment: There is an unofficial principle that suggests we have only 79 columns for each line